# How to synchronize write to file from a MemoryString's in different Threads in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

My threads use file compression by blocks. Then I need to save it back to disk.
Code looks something like this:

```
static void WorkerCompression()
{
    using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(FilePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (MemoryMappedViewStream inputStream = mmf.CreateViewStream(offset, size, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
                {
                    inputStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
                }

                // Try to sync save in file from 'outputStream' here
            }
        }
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < processors; i++)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(WorkerCompression);
        thread.Name = i.ToString();
        thread.Start();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

How can I sync a save to a file? Is there a way to wait for a signal until first stream finishes working, after append file second stream receive signal, append it and so on?

Comment: As long as only 1 thread is reading and only 1 is writing, there is no need to synchronize.

Comment: I am running 8 threads. Everyone reads the same length at their offset, compresses this block and I need to save it. There are absolutely exactly 8 threads.

Comment: How do you coordinate that they write in the right order? Or is the compression only on segement size?

Comment: I do not coordinate the recording now. That is what I want to know.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If you only want one worker to run at a time, then you don't need multiple workers at all. Just do everything in a single thread. Frankly, `ManualResetEvent` is probably about the worst, least-convenient, least-efficient, least-maintainable way to handle thread synchronization here, but until your question includes enough detail to understand how you expect this to even _work_ (i.e. produce a file that is coherent), the best advice is to not do this at all.

Comment: The main hard work is done in different threads. All I have to do is save the file correctly.

Comment: Your goal is to compress a single file as fast as possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using threads, you have to create your signal yourself.

You could pass a ManualResetEvent to your method, and signal it at the end.

```
static void WorkerCompression(ManualResetEvent finished)
{
       /* do your stuff*/
       finished.Set();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[processors];
    for (int i = 0; i < processors; i++)
   {
      handles[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
      var thread = new Thread(WorkerCompression);
      thread.Name = i.ToString();
      thread.Start(handles[i]);
   }
   WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles)
   /* here we arrive only if all is finished*/

   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But using a Task and using Task.WaitAll is doing exactly the same, with less effort.

If you want to do, one job after the other, don't use threads !

Comment: OMG! I'm rly stupid. I was thinking about ManualResetEvent, but couldn't figure out how to use only one. I did not guess to use an array of ManualResetEvent. Thanks!

Comment: Good you are on track. There is only one parameter allowed per thread method, usually you create a class or structure that contain all the parameters you need inside your thread. The finished-event is most often just one of many parameters. you may want to pass filepositions and things like that also. Alternativly create a class representing your Thread and make your WorkerCompression an instance method, so you have access to this class with properties from inside and outside the thread.

Comment: Sorry. I did not specify. The problem is that there are 8 threads, but they are wrapped in while(CurrentOffset < OriginalFile.Length). That is, the first thread after the end will work out the next block. Therefore, I can not expect the end of all threads in main methoid. I need to somehow find out what exactly the thread that is responsible for the first block finished the job (for example, thread 5), then the thread that finished the second block (for example, thread 3). Any ideas?

Comment: It is you, who defines, which thread is doing what. You know at startup which thread starts at offset 0, don't you ? I'm not even sure what "first block finished" means, the finishing of the Block with offset 0, or the first finished block no matter which one, The first thread finished you get with WaitOne.

Comment: I have solved the sync issue using additional method in main thread and AutoResetEvent. Later I will write my solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Multitasking and Multithreading are not a guaranteed speedup. You need to pick problems for them very carefully. If you apply them to the wrong problems, you end up with code that is more complex/prone to errors, more memory demanding and most importantly *slower* then a simple, sequential thing.

File and Network operations are way up there with "things that can not be multitasked". They are usually Disk/Network bound. Now putting the whole loop going over the files into a single seperate task? That is so normal, you can not even write a Word Processor without that. Using one of hte pre-written Enumerator classes so the System might pre-load the next line during processing of one? Adviseable. But Mutltitasking on a per-File or even per-File Segment level? That is most likely just shooting yourself in the foot.

With Network it makes the most sense, as you may run into per-connection Bandwidth Limits. But even in this case, it [might not mater that much](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

As I understand it, you read a segment of the file, do some processing on each segment and then write them to the output file. Now this will only work if the *order of segments in the output file does not mater*. In about 95% of all cases the order does mater, and we are at "this will not even solve the problem".

For most of the cases, you can not even process a *segment* without having all preceeding segments processed. Particular Encryption and Hashing are *inherently sequential by design*. We have nothing close to the data needed to tell you if that is one of those 5%.

Edit:

> I perform long-term encryption of ~10,000 large blocks, and then I need to write them to a file in the correct order. While new blocks are being processed, another thread is writing already processed in the correct order (or waiting for the processing of the desired block - it is usually within

If the order maters, the best I can give you quickly and reliably is 3 Threads:

- 1 that reads from the file
- 1 that processes the blocks in order
- 1 that writes the blocks to the output
- The 3 would use 2 `Channel`s or ConcurrentQueues to talk witn one another.

At least one of those threads - more likely 2 - will be idling most of the time. My bet is on Proessor waiting on Reader, and Writer waiting on Processor. But it will avoid the overheads from 1-2 sides interering with the other. That is a Enumerator level speedup.

If you still insist on having Multiple processor threads (wich I can not advise against *enough*), what you need to do is take a Page from Networking and add the [Sequence Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) for each block. They primarily use it for Error Detection. But you would have to use it for error detection/reaction:

- The Writer sets the running number
- The Processors will just hand it through
- The Writer will not write any given number, until and unless it has written all previous numbers. If you still use Queues or Channels, the Writer will need it's own buffer Collection in case the blocks appear out of order.

Comment: I perform long-term encryption of ~10,000 large blocks, and then I need to write them to a file in the correct order. While new blocks are being processed, another thread is writing already processed in the correct order (or waiting for the processing of the desired block - it is usually within <n processings, where 'n' is the number of threads/CPU cores)